# Azure YAML Scripts - Build and Release

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Can we have both build and release in the same YAML script in Azure DevOps ? If yes, Can someone help me with the sample script. For the release part, we are deploying to multiple environments.

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple way to initiate build and release our configurations via Azure DevOps.

Firstly, we’ll be looking at building CI and CD in two different yml formats and create two pipelines to automate our tasks. For that we’ll be using Resources in YAML Pipelines.

Now we will be creating build pipeline by creating new DevOps project and new repository, can add below yaml file as build-pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    exclude:
    - build-pipeline.yml
    - release-pipeline.yml

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:  
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: $(vmImageName)
  steps:
  - script: | 
      echo 'do some unit test'
    displayName: 'unit test'
  - script: | 
      echo 'compile application'
    displayName: 'compile'
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Archive files'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: zip
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      replaceExistingArchive: true
  - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    artifact: drop
```

Similarly, we create a release pipeline and below is the yml format:

```
# Explicitly set none for repositry trigger
trigger:
- none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: myappbuild  # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: myapp-build-pipeline # Name of the triggering pipeline
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - master

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
- deployment: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy
  environment: dev
  pool: 
    vmImage: $(vmImageName)
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:          
        - download: myappbuild
          artifact: drop  
        - task: ExtractFiles@1
          inputs:
            archiveFilePatterns: '$(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/myappbuild/drop/$(resources.pipeline.myappbuild.runID).zip'
            destinationFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)'
            cleanDestinationFolder: false
        - script: |  
            cat $(agent.builddirectory)/greatcode.txt
```

Here we can understand that build pipeline runs first, then release pipeline runs and these pipelines can be linked with multiple deployments.

Also, we have more information on few useful blogs such as [c-sharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learning-azure-devops-build-and-release-pipeline/#:%7E:text=%20Learning%20Azure%20Devops%20-%20Build%20And%20Release,will%20be%20able%20to%20see%20the...%20More%20), [adamtheautomater](https://adamtheautomator.com/azure-pipelines/#Building_an_Azure_DevOps_Release_Pipeline). Thanks to the bloggers.

Comment: Thanks,this helps but how do we specify for multiple environments like dev,test,prod etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample YAML script that is building a react project and deploying this react app into Azure App Services.
You could add more stages and name them as per your requirements.
For dependency on previous stages, you can add `dependson` condition to the stage and `onsucceeded('stage_name')` under stage.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - develop
  paths:
    include:
    - pipelines/azure_multi_stage_pipeline.yml 

stages:
# *****************  Build Stage starts here ******************** #
- stage: buildStage
  jobs:
  - job: buildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: npm install
      inputs:
        command: 'install'
        workingDir: 'code/.'
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: npm run build
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        workingDir: 'code/.'
        customCommand: 'run build'
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: "Archiving Artifacts"
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: 'code/'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: 'react_stopwatch'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: 'react_stopwatch.zip'
        ArtifactName: 'react_stopwatch'
        publishLocation: Container

# *****************  Deployment Stage starts here ******************** #
- stage: deployStage
  dependsOn: buildStage
  condition: succeeded('buildStage')
  jobs:
  - job: deployJob
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: downloadArtifacts
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'react_stopwatch'
        downloadPath: '.'
        cleanDestinationFolder: true
    
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: deployToAzure
      inputs:
        ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
        azureSubscription: 'Azure Subscription'
        appType: 'webAppLinux'
        WebAppName: '<app_name>'
        packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/react_stopwatch/react_stopwatch.zip'
        RuntimeStack: 'NODE|16-lts'
        StartupCommand: 'npm start'
```